# 2 columns one below another in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

```
select cap2 as captain from data group by cap2
union all
select cap3 as captain from data group by cap3
```

I'm getting this error

> ORA-12704: character set mismatch

can you please help me to fix this

Comment: Show us the table definition.

Comment: BTW, use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get distinct rows, not `GROUP BY`. But here you should use `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` to eliminate duplicates, simply  `select cap2 as captain from data UNION select cap3 as captain from data`.

Comment: I get same error when i use UNION

Comment: Are cap2 and cap3 the same datatypes? If not, that might be it.

Comment: My second comment was a tip/recommendation. My first comment was an instruction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See whether this helps.

I presume that this is your situation:

```
SQL> create table test
  2    (cap2 varchar2(10),
  3     cap3 nvarchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('A', 'B');

1 row created.
```

This is your current query:

```
SQL> select cap2 from test
  2  union
  3  select cap3 from test;
select cap2 from test
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12704: character set mismatch
```

This is what you might try to do - apply the `to_char` function to a `nvarchar2` column:

```
SQL> select cap2 from test
  2  union
  3  select to_char(cap3) from test;

CAP2
----------------------------------------
A
B

SQL>
```

Comment: your answer helped me a lot

Comment: I'm glad if it did.